# Number of objects vs Payload, while scaling a modern Javascript project which is more important?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, reactjs, javascript-objects

of course, less payload equals to less number of objects but please read the whole description below.

While scaling a javascript project on a modern browser which one is more important? The size of data payload or the number of javascript objects in the memory. I have a huge JSON string which I am looping around and chopping that huge string into different objects. The JSON string holds a lot of traveller information, and each Javascript object has a lot of properties. When there are more than 10,000 travellers in the JSON, the browser is struggling to perform.

I am bringing a lot of properties unnecessary if I can reduce the number of properties obviously my payload will decrease, still, the number of objects might stay the same.

A number of JS objects vs Smaller payload, which one gives more buck for the money regarding the performance?

Thanks

Comment: Are the 10,000 travellers all the data in your database? Why are you processing all of them at once? It seems like some of that stuff might be better suited for the backend or you should send less info to the frontend.

Comment: I don't think objects with less properties with matter much if you are still looping through all the objects. I think there should be more data and info about how you are specifically dealing with the data to better investigate the efficiency issue.

Comment: Hello @nbkhope we have millions of travellers in the database. At times we bring more than 10k rows then the browser seems lagging. If the retrieved data is low then the application is working nice and smooth.

Comment: Of possible interest [JSON.parse() on a large array of objects is using way more memory than it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564728/json-parse-on-a-large-array-of-objects-is-using-way-more-memory-than-it-should#30565208)

Comment: It all depends on what you're actually doing with the data, and where the bottleneck is. JS is fast, 10k objects is not that many, JS will handle it / manipulate it fine. But if you're saying that you're parsing a 10MB json string which builds 10k objects, then yes that's going to be slow.

Answer (score 3):

I like some of the answers I've read, but I think I would approach the question of the bottle neck in a different way, by which I hope you could avoid future bottle necks as well.

Most answers assume that the number of objects is the bottleneck. I think this isn't the case. I believe the bottleneck is the fact that the JavaScript event loop gets excessively backlogged.

As you well know, JavaScript runs only a single thread and an event loop.

Each function you call is actually a callback for such events.

However, since there is only a single thread, any code in the web page has **to wait** for each event to complete before any other task can be performed.

**This means that it's more important for JavaScript functions to be fragmented (into micro events/callbacks) than for any single function to be performance oriented**.

In your case, you're both looping over a long string and performing actions - **without returning the control to the event loop** - which means the browser has to wait for this big chunk of code to complete before it can process any more data / events.

The question of data collection / processing can be argued over. Is it better to get a lot of small messages (placing, perhaps, more load on the network / server)? Is it better to receive a huge string and process it by chunks? ...

... I don't know, this really depends on other factors, such as the server's design, the database's design, the client load, update interval, etc'.

If you do prefer to process a single huge string, it might be better to process it a bit at a time and then forward it to a callback for future processing.

i.e. for a `\n` seperated JSON string, you could try:

```
function consumeString(s) {
    if(s.length == 0)
        return;
    var sep = s.indexOf("\n");
    if(sep < 0)
        sep = s.length;
    try {
        var obj = JSON.parse(s.slice(0, sep));
        console.log("processed:", obj);
    } catch {
        console.log("Failed... not valid JSON?:");
    }
    // schedule the next slice for later processing.
    setTimeout(consumeString, 0, s.slice(sep + 1));
}


var text = '{ "employees" : [' + // JSON1
'{ "firstName":"John 1" , "lastName":"Doe 1" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna 1" , "lastName":"Smith 1" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter 1" , "lastName":"Jones 1" } ]}' + // END JSON1
"\n" +
'{ "employees" : [' + // JSON2
'{ "firstName":"John 2" , "lastName":"Doe 2" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna 2" , "lastName":"Smith 2" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter 2" , "lastName":"Jones 2" } ]}';

consumeString(text);
```

This is just an outline, obviously, but although it seems less performant (it wastes time rescheduling itself and is constantly interrupted, increasing the chance for CPU cache misses)... it actually helps the browser remain responsive and improves the perceived performance, from a user's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

10,000 object don't seem a lot for modern JavaScript VMs. Your problem seems to stem from the fact that you are processing a large amount of String in memory and Updating DOM both of which are slow and memory intensive operations.

Note that [Strings are immutable in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), so every time you are chopping it you are creating new instance of it in memory. This is especially bad if you are doing String manipulation inside a loop.
Every iteration will lead to creation of a new String object in memory. The old one is now discarded but might not get garbage collected immediately so will eat up memory. Problem will get worse if you are manipulating large chunks of strings. Javascript is not really good for doing this type of long running in-memory operations because it is [single threaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). And such operations tie up the main thread which makes your application slow.

```
while(...) {
  // this will create a new instance of fullStr in memory every iteration
  fullStr = fullStr + 'str1';
}
```

DOM manipulation can be really slow even with modern JS libraries like React if not done correctly. If you keep rendering new rows by appending new nodes to existing DOM you will see performance problems. DOM manipulation leads to reflows and repaints both of which are very [slow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) and computationally intensive. Every call to `render` might cause a complete reflow and repaint. If your higher order component gets rendered on prop change, it might force all the child components to re-render which slows down you page. React does take care of some of these concerns by batching updates.

Another thing that a lot of people don't consider is the side-effect of using event handlers for events like `mousemove` or `scroll`. Every tiny movement might cause an element on a page to change in some way that might cause repaint or reflow of other parts of the DOM too. Things can get worse when using lot of animations on the page. These type of event handlers can also tie up VMs event loop by constantly firing. One to tackle this problem would be to use [throttling](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Least likely but something to consider, objects when created, have an extra overhead of keeping count of references. To us it might look like VM is storing an object with all it's properties and values in a contiguous block of memory. However, in [reality](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2017/03/29/v8-object-size.html#a-simple-example-and-a-naive-guess) objects store references to actual values stored else where in memory. This overhead can be non-trivial for large number of objects.

There is a misconception that creating a new instance of a `class` or `function` causes lot of memory overhead as all properties are and values are cloned. This is **not** true. Use of `prototypes` by JavaScript cuts down memory usage by sharing the same properties with all the instances of of a particular class or function. That is why prototypal inheritance is very efficient in terms of memory usage. Deep prototype chains might cause slow lookups though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the best answer I can, considering that my areas of expertise only cross the scope of this question rather than fully covering it.

Modern computers have a memory hierarchy: main memory; two or three levels of caches. Each level of cache is smaller but nearer to the CPU (and so faster, in effect) than the one above it.

Therefore, in terms of the speed at which a program runs, it tends to be less important how much overall memory it is using than the current 'working set' - the parts of memory that the program is making use of at one moment in time.

From your description, it sounds like breaking up the big JSON string into a lot of smaller objects would help reduce the size of the working set most of the time. If, in doing this, you are left with a lot of unused properties, that probably won't matter, because they will probably remain outside the working set most of the time.

It might be a useful technique to have the back end filter out some of the properties that are not needed, simply because this will reduce the amount of data being transmitted. However, you need to carefully consider how this would scale; it might put too much load on the server(s).

It may be that there are ways to speed up your program by re-assessing the algorithms you have coded and the library (methods) you use. There may be some techniques specific to typical modern JavaScript engines; I'm afraid this is outside my expertise.

It might help to introduce some new concepts into your application. Might it be acceptable for the processing to be reduced by adopting heuristics (systematic guesswork) or reduced accuracy?

For example, users could be presented with interim results based on a first pass that only uses some of the data. A spinner (or message) could be used to alert the user that more processing is going on. When the full data set has been processed, present that to the user.

Or, give the user the choice of 'quick' or 'deep' results; the deep results might be computed on the back end instead (and possibly this could be farmed out to machines other than the HTTP or database server(s)).

HTH & Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably number of the JavaScript objects is the bottleneck in your scenario. You can make a few simple controls such as checking if the operating system falls into swap. Below I paste a MacOs activity monitor screenshot where you can check the swap usage. Same info exists for both Linux and Windows operating systems as well.

[image]

Another control method can be, check how much filter / map / reduce / each operations you are making with your data. If you do a lot of such operations, it increases the probability that your code is stuck with the amount of the objects. Try either to reduce the number of objects (which you are already aware of) or to reduce the need to iterate over objects repetitively (for example if you find same information over and over again, store it to an intermediate object).

Answer (score 0):

Each property in your object is itself an object. Javascript is funny that way.

*Example*

```
myObject {
    prop1: 'hello',
}
```

Here you have an 'Object' `myObject` which inherits from the `Object` prototype and carries with it all the overhead of an object. This object contains a property, `prop1` which is a string. A string inherits from `String` which inherits from `Object`. So your string is also carrying with it all the overhead of an object. So having more properties should be roughly the same regarding memory usage as having more objects.

> am bringing a lot of properties unnecessary if I can reduce the number of properties obviously my payload will decrease, still, the number of objects might stay the same.
>
> A number of JS objects vs Smaller payload, which one gives more buck for the money regarding the performance?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean here, but it sounds like your are saying that you definitely need all 10,000 travelers, but you would be fine if each traveler had maybe 20 properties instead of 100.

Yes! Do that. Less data means less to keep track of in memory, a smaller stack to dig through to find your data again, etc. etc. 10000 * 20 is much better than 10000 * 100 here.

However, I still encourage you to rethink whether it makes sense to bring this many data points into the browser at all. There are not many use cases I can think of where you would even be able to display it all. Much better to let your server process the data more, then just send the small subset you can actually fit on the screen.

The server can spend its cpu time converting the data into useful bite-size chunks, while the browser spends its cpu time making the user experience silky-smooth.

Comment: Your statement "which inherits from the Object prototype and carries with it all the overhead of an object", isn't a correct statement. The beauty of using `prototype` is that there is ever only one instance of a property which is shared with all the instances. All your Objects or Strings will share the same prototype chain so will not cause memory bloat. One thing that can happen is that as your prototype chain grows longer the property lookup becomes slower. This is the basis of JavaScript inheritance.

Comment: Yes. That's the beauty of prototypal inheritance. "All the overhead of an object" isn't really much overhead at all. But that doesn't change my main point, which is that _each property is roughly equal weight to the parent object it is attached to_. If you feel I did not describe this accurately, feel free to make an edit as long as you don't lose that point. You can quote this comment in the edit-reason if you need it to pass peer review.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write the data into IndexedDB, then query the ones that you actually need, I doubt you'll ever need to show all the 10k objects at once. This way you won't hold a big chunk of data in the memory, but you'll still be able to access it. Take a look at [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org/) it has very simple api. Maybe it worth a try.